# Wix Custom Action fails to create SymbolicLink on Windows 7

Tags: winapi, wix

I am working on a Wix installer that creates a SymbolicLink inside a custom action. The custom action is written in C#. It is creating the SymbolicLink by calling the [CreateSymbolicLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API. On Windows 10, the call works perfectly. On Windows 7 it fails. If I call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), it returns an error code of 997, which is [ERROR_IO_PENDING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here is the line of code the calls the API:

```
var result = CreateSymbolicLink(pathToCreateLink, installDir, SymbolicLinkFlags.Directory | SymbolicLinkFlags.UnprivilegedCreate);
if(!result)
{
     _logger.Log($"Win32 Error Code: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
}
```

Here is the Dll Import:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink( string lpSymlinkFileName, string pTargetFileName, SymbolicLinkFlags dwFlags);
```

The custom action is invoked with Execute set to "[deferred](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html)" and Impersonate set to "no".

If I put the line of C# code in a console application, it functions correctly (even on Windows 7). So there is something about how the code is being called in the installer that is causing the error.

Part of my problem is that I can find very little information on the error code, so I can't be sure what to try to fix it.

Comment: That does sound scary. With an error like that, I would abandon the symlink approach - especially if the deployment is large in scope.

It smells like something deep in the system, or some special condition that exists on your Windows 7 box. Did you test on several Windows 7 boxes?

Comment: We don't even know, whether that *is* the error code you get. You may be calling `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` at the wrong time, or your P/Invoke declaration doesn't set the `SetLastError` attribute to `true`. We don't know either way. Voting to close.

Comment: It may also be useful to say where you are getting the actual values from, in case you are using (for example) folder values that are user-oriented that don't apply to the system account.

Answer (score 1):

A kind of confirmation can be found in wixsharp code. They encountered this problem and could not surpass it.
https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/blob/master/Source/src/WixSharp/ResilientPackage.cs

The w/a I implemented in my installer is repeating symbolic links creation via cmd tool mklink and if it fails as well, just copy files.

Answer (score 0):

MSI packages run as System TrustedInstaller, and on Windows 7 that user does not have access to create SymLinks with the default Local Security Policy.

I fixed it by using junctions instead (`mklink /j`), but that only works for folders.